# Java - get the newest file in a directory?

Tags: java, file-io, filesystems

Does anybody have a snippet of Java that can return the newest file in a directory (or knowledge of a library that simplifies this sort of thing)?

Answer (score 74):

The following code returns the last modified file or folder:

```
public static File getLastModified(String directoryFilePath)
{
    File directory = new File(directoryFilePath);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles(File::isFile);
    long lastModifiedTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    File chosenFile = null;

    if (files != null)
    {
        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (file.lastModified() > lastModifiedTime)
            {
                chosenFile = file;
                lastModifiedTime = file.lastModified();
            }
        }
    }

    return chosenFile;
}
```

Note that it required `Java 8` or newer due to the lambda expression.

Comment: Remember to check that listFiles() doesn't return null.

Comment: Add on more check files != null && files.length > 0

Answer (score 42):

In Java 8:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("./path/somewhere");  // specify your directory

Optional<Path> lastFilePath = Files.list(dir)    // here we get the stream with full directory listing
    .filter(f -> !Files.isDirectory(f))  // exclude subdirectories from listing
    .max(Comparator.comparingLong(f -> f.toFile().lastModified()));  // finally get the last file using simple comparator by lastModified field

if ( lastFilePath.isPresent() ) // your folder may be empty
{
    // do your code here, lastFilePath contains all you need
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump your code. Explain your train of thought so we can better understand your answer. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if the difference between the two last-modified timestamps is larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: There is a typo in your example: isPresented() should be isPresent()

Comment: is it possible without loading full files list? In cases when directory is too large.

Answer (score 17):

This works perfectly fine for me:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;

...

/* Get the newest file for a specific extension */
public File getTheNewestFile(String filePath, String ext) {
    File theNewestFile = null;
    File dir = new File(filePath);
    FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*." + ext);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);

    if (files.length > 0) {
        /** The newest file comes first **/
        Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
        theNewestFile = files[0];
    }

    return theNewestFile;
}
```

Comment: c'mon, you don't have to SORT array to get minimum value!

Comment: Maybe perfect, but no fast

Comment: What if we are not updating the directory it will give the same result every time.?

Answer (score 2):

```
private File getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath){
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
       if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
           lastModifiedFile = files[i];
       }
    }
    return lastModifiedFile;
}
```

Comment: guys you can use this code for get last modified file.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;


public class Newest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dir = new File("C:\\your\\dir");
        File [] files  = dir.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator(){
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return compare( (File)o1, (File)o2);
            }
            private int compare( File f1, File f2){
                long result = f2.lastModified() - f1.lastModified();
                if( result > 0 ){
                    return 1;
                } else if( result < 0 ){
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println( Arrays.asList(files ));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's kind of wonky to force a ClassCastException in the non-File case, instead of, say, asserting instanceof.

Comment: You won't get a non-File from the array returned by File.listFiles();

Comment: c'mon, you don't have to SORT array to get minimum value!

Comment: Why don't you use new Comparator<File>()? This avoids the cast and the extra function.

Answer (score 1):

```
public File getLastDownloadedFile() {
    File choice = null;
    try {
        File fl = new File("C:/Users/" + System.getProperty("user.name")
                + "/Downloads/");
        File[] files = fl.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.isFile();
            }
        });
//Sleep to download file if not required can be removed
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        long lastMod = Long.MIN_VALUE;

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.lastModified() > lastMod) {
                choice = file;
                lastMod = file.lastModified();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while getting the last download file :"
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("The last downloaded file is " + choice.getPath());
    System.out.println("The last downloaded file is " + choice.getPath(),true);
    return choice;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the most recent created file, I made this because when you create a file in some situations, it may not always have the correct modified date.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;

private File lastFileCreated(String dir) {
    File fl = new File(dir);
    File[] files = fl.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    FileTime lastCreated = null;
    File choice = null;

    for (File file : files) {
        BasicFileAttributes attr=null;
        try {
            attr = Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        if(lastCreated ==null)
            lastCreated = attr.creationTime();

        if (attr!=null&&attr.creationTime().compareTo(lastCreated)==0) {
            choice = file;
        }
    }
    return choice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small modification to Jose's code which makes sure the folder has at least 1 file in it. Work's great in my app!

```
public static File lastFileModified(String dir) {
        File fl = new File(dir);
        File choice = null;
        if (fl.listFiles().length>0) {
            File[] files = fl.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    return file.isFile();
                }
            });
            long lastMod = Long.MIN_VALUE;

            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.lastModified() > lastMod) {
                    choice = file;
                    lastMod = file.lastModified();
                }
            }
        }
        return choice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me well:

```
public String pickLatestFileFromDownloads() {

        String currentUsersHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");

        String downloadFolder = currentUsersHomeDir + File.separator + "Downloads" + File.separator;

        File dir = new File(downloadFolder);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
            testLogger.info("There is no file in the folder");
        }

        File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
                lastModifiedFile = files[i];
            }
        }
        String k = lastModifiedFile.toString();

        System.out.println(lastModifiedFile);
        Path p = Paths.get(k);
        String file = p.getFileName().toString();
        return file;

    }

//PostedBy: saurabh Gupta Aricent-provar
```