# Java - Read all .txt files in folder

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Let's say, I have a folder called `maps` and inside `maps` I have `map1.txt`, `map2.txt,` and `map3.txt`. How can I use Java and the `BufferReader` to read all of the `.txt` files in folder `maps` (if it is at all possible)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read all files in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Something like the following should get you going, note that I use apache commons FileUtils instead of messing with buffers and streams for simplicity...

```
File folder = new File("/path/to/files");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  File file = listOfFiles[i];
  if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    /* do somthing with content */
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks... but a note: would it make it easier to manage if all of the files were named mapNUMBER.txt? As in map3.txt, map4.txt, etc.

Comment: This code won't work as is because there's no declaration of the variable 'file' used on line 6. Not sure why you would write it up this way, maybe it's supposed to be more pseudocode style, but file should be replaced with listOfFiles[i], or the file variable should be declared if it's going to be used.

Comment: Just for the record, `for(File file : folder.listFiles())` is quite a bit shorter and nicer. :)

Comment: @Dolda2000 agreed, I am not real sure why I answered this way. Perhaps I pulled an existing example.

Answer (score 22):

I would take @Andrew White answer (+1 BTW) one step further, and suggest you would use FileNameFilter to list only relevant files:

```
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".txt");
    }
};

File folder = new File("/path/to/files");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    File file = listOfFiles[i];
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    // do something with the file
}
```

Comment: @Shahryar it's not a redundant answer, it's a different and valid answer.

Comment: @KennyCason As I see it's just like previous answer! What is the  advantage of using FileNameFilter?

Comment: @Shahryar yes, which is imo an equal, and possibly, a cleaner example. It's also good to know the existence of `other` solutions. You'll see on SO that there are many similar, but different solutions to a problem are supplied.

Comment: @KennyCason "It's also good to know the existence of other solutions" good word :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
    final File folder = new File("C:/Dev Tools/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/ROOT/somefile");
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
           System.out.println("FileEntry Directory "+fileEntry);
```

Comment: Does this add any improvement over the other answers? Or is the for-each just a syntax preference?

Comment: It does the same, Only difference that it is clean and less code.

Answer (score 1):

With `NIO` you can do the following:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/files"))
          .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
          .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt"))
          .map(FileUtils::readFileToString)
          // do something
```

To read the file contents you may use `Files#readString` but, as usual, you need to handle `IOException` inside lambda expression.

Comment: Surround with `try/catch` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good way to read all .txt files from maps and sub folder's

```
 private static void addfiles (File input,ArrayList<File> files)
{
    if(input.isDirectory())
    {
        ArrayList <File> path = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(input.listFiles()));
        for(int i=0 ; i<path.size();++i)
        {
            if(path.get(i).isDirectory())
            {
                addfiles(path.get(i),files);
            }
            if(path.get(i).isFile())
            {
                String name=(path.get(i)).getName();
                if(name.lastIndexOf('.')>0)
                {
                    int lastIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
                    String str = name.substring(lastIndex);
                    if(str.equals(".txt"))
                    {
                        files.add(path.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(input.isFile())
    {
        String name=(input.getName());
        if(name.lastIndexOf('.')>0)
        {
            int lastIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
            String str = name.substring(lastIndex);
            if(str.equals(".txt"))
            {
                files.add(input);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better way of doing this using the new java.nio api, then this is the way, taken from [the java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html)

```
Path dir = ...;
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream =
     Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.txt")) {
    for (Path entry: stream) {
        System.out.println(entry.getFileName());
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    // IOException can never be thrown by the iteration.
    // In this snippet, it can // only be thrown by newDirectoryStream.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only JDK, If all your files are in one directory:

```
File dir = new File("path/to/files/");

for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    // do something with file
    s.close();
}
```

To exclude files, you can use `listFiles(FileFilter)`