# Read Information from .XML file

Tags: java, algorithm, file, jaxb

Imagine i have .xml file with the below format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<config>
    <Directory>c:/test</Directory>
    <headerLine>1</headerLine>
    <pattern>.*\.txt</pattern>
</config>
```

The `<Directory>` tag, Specify the path of the file.

The `<headerLine>` tags, specify how many lines of my file have a header and the other is Body.(Not Important)

The `<pattern>` tags. specify the Format of the files.

the question is:

i want to read a file. first of all, i have to go to `<Directory>` tag, and get the directory of my files, then i have to read all of the files in that directory with the specify pattern, that shows in  tags.
for example .in C:/test , i have many file, but i should read files, that terminated with ".*.txt" .
i use "Unmarshal" algorithm to read from .xml and convert it to java object.
my problem, is how can i defind to read all of the files in c:/test directory with that pattern.
could you please help me, how can i solve this problem?

```
FileSplitter fileSplitter = new FileSplitter("C:\\test.txt");
```

with this code, i can read just `test.txt` file, but i want to read directories with specific pattern.

Comment: There are many method to read XML. Use DOM, SAX etc. For details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/

Comment: You are asking how read XML or how read files with regex ?

Comment: Try this for reading files from directory http://stackoverflow.com/a/5924345/1862502

Comment: my question is how read file with "regex"

Comment: You can just use FilenameFilter as @VigneshVino suggested. Nothing is keeping you from using a regular expression in the `accept()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, That,s right.
as what is "Vignesh Vino" suggested, this code, solve my problem and answer my question

```
File folder = new File("/path/to/files");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  File file = listOfFiles[i];
  if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    /* do somthing with content */
  } 
}
```