# Java - Read many txt files on a folder and process them

Tags: java

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924237/java-read-all-txt-files-in-folder):

Now in my case i have 720 files named in this way: "dom 24 mar 2013_00.50.35_128.txt", every file has a different date and time. In testing phase i used Scanner, with a specific txt file, to do some operations on it:

> Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("stuff.txt"));

My question is:

How can i reuse scanner and read all 720 files without having to set the precise name on scanner?

Thanks

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189094/how-to-scan-a-folder-in-java

Comment: Can you just read all the files in the directory, or you have more files that you don't want to be read with different naming schemes in the directory as well?

Comment: You can't. A new scanner would be created for each file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you have all the files in one place:

```
File dir = new File("path/to/files/");

for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    ...
    s.close();
}
```

Note that if you have any files that you don't want to include, you can give `listFiles()` a [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) argument to filter them out.

Comment: Yes, all the files are in the same folder.

Comment: Damn, you just beat me to it :) +1 for beating me to the answer

Comment: how can we read the multiple files in case the files are located in different directories ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, create your file object by pointing it to a directory and then list the files of that directory.

```
File dir = new File("Dir/ToYour/Files");

if(dir.isDir()) {
   for(File file : dir.listFiles()) {
      if(file.isFile()) {
         //do stuff on a file
      }
   }
} else {
   //do stuff on a file
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this in this way

```
 File folder = new File("D:\\DestFile");
 File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

 for (File file : listOfFiles) {
 if (file.isFile()&&(file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf('.')+1).equals("txt"))) {
   // Scanner 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    File file = new File(folderNameFromWhereToRead);

    if(file!=null && file.exists()){
        File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles();

        if(listOfFiles!=null){

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                      // DO work
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think your `if(listOfFiles!=null)` is unnecessary.  You just created the `listOfFiles` so how can it be null?

Comment: Ughh.. same with your `if(file!=null)`... you're testing whether an object reference exist which you just made prior to the test!

Comment: Null check on `lisOfFiles` is okay (it could happen if the path exists but is a file) but on the `file` isn't required. +1 for the `isFile()` check anyway.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal good call, I didn't think about that with `listOfFiles` because I would have written my code to first check if `file` is a directory and then processed `listFiles()`.