# Accessing .txt files from inside a folder (java)

Tags: java, file, fileutils

I have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924237/java-read-all-txt-files-in-folder), and I tried the answer that the question accepted:

```
File folder = new File("/path/to/files");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  File file = listOfFiles[i];
  if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
    /* do somthing with content */
  } 
}
```

Only when I tried compiling, it couldn't find the variable `FileUtils`. Is there a java package that I have to import at the beginning of my program to use class `File` methods? I've never used `File` objects before, so I'm trying to learn to be able to work with and manipulate them. Thanks.

Comment: FileUtils is from Apache Commons IO library & to use FileUtils you need this jar file .Then import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils to your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Apache Commons FileUtils
. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

You would need to import `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`

Comment: Opps I am a bit late.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html
```

Check here for file file utils.