# How to get a list of files from within a folder structure

Tags: java, file, compiler-construction

im creating a program that will compile java files, at the moment i have the program compiling numerous files at a time in one particular folder. but what i want it to do is to compile all the files in a folder structure given a folder to start (eg. if given the following address `C:/files_to_be_compiled`, can you search all the folders within this folder to get a list of all the .class files). I have this code that is getting all the `.class` files from a single folder but i need to expand this to get all the `.class` files from all the rest of the folders in that folder given

```
 String files;
        File folder = new File("C:/files_to_compile");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    if (files.endsWith(".class") || files.endsWith(".CLASS")) {
                        System.out.println(files);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

how would i extend the code above get all the .class files from within all the folders in a given folder?

Comment: exact duplicate of [Read all files in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: You should use recursion to traverse all directories within the current directory to scan for .class files.. also, use .toLowerCase() instead of comparing .class AND .CLASS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846349/339852) may be of use to you.

**Example code borrowed from linked answer:**

```
public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
        }
    }
}

final File folder = new File("/home/you/Desktop");
listFilesForFolder(folder);
```

Comment: you should vote to close the question, not just plagiarise the other question's answer.

Comment: @Alnitak: Plagiarizing consists of "stealing" text from another source without referencing the source. By that definition I am not plagiarizing the other answer.

Comment: ok, perhaps that was a little strong, but the point still stands - you identified an identical question, the standard procedure is to vote to close.

Comment: @Alnitak: what Elliot says is true and it answered my question as well so it should actually be marked up not down

Comment: @newSpringer I didn't mark it down.  I didn't vote it up either, though - IMHO getting up votes requires work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somwthing like

```
void analyze(File folder){
    String files;        
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                if (files.endsWith(".class") || files.endsWith(".CLASS")) {
                    System.out.println(files);
                }
            } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()){
                analyze(listOfFiles[i]);
        }
    }
 }

void start(){
    File folder = new File("C:/files_to_compile");
    analyze(folder);
}
```

This way, you're analyzing your structure recursively (Depth-first search).

Comment: To prevent extensions like .Class or .cLaSs from slipping through, you might want to do a check like `filename.toUppercase().endsWith(".CLASS")`

Comment: I know, but this is his code, I've just added the `else if` part :) Good point though!

Comment: @Zom-B: It isn't a good point which you will recognize, if you put your ClAsS-files into a jar, and try to find them there, maybe on different plattforms. I've never seen a compiler not producing lowercase, and if there is, it should fail early, to be fixed.

Comment: `filename.toUppercase()` doesn't mean that the compiler will produce only uppercase files, it's just used to check the file extension without taking care of the string format. And a `.ClAsS` file is not valid in Java. (Assuming that I understood what you're saying!)

Comment: @StepTNT: when you say You just need to use a method to call analyze(starting-folder-here), do you create a new file (File folder2 = new File("files_to_compile");) and put that into analyze(folder2)?

Comment: @StepTNT: thanks, ya was thinking that was the way to do it alright

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void listFilesForFolder(String path)
{
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    for(File file : files)
    {
        if (file.isDirectory()){
            listFilesForFolder(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else if (file.isFile())
        {
            // your code goes here
        }
    }
}

// run
listFilesForFolder("C:/files_to_compile");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DirectoryWalker](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/DirectoryWalker.html) from Apache Commons to walk through a directory hierarchy and apply a filter - `FileFilterUtils.suffixFileFilter(".class")`. For example:

```
public class ClassFileWalker extends DirectoryWalker {
    public ClassFileWalker() {
        super(FileFilterUtils.directoryFileFilter(), 
                FileFilterUtils.suffixFileFilter(".class"), -1);
    }

    protected void handleFile(File file, int depth, Collection results) {
        if(file.isFile())
            results.add(file);
    }

    public List<File> getFiles(String location) {
        List<File> files = Lists.newArrayList();
        try {
            walk(new File(location), files);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return files;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
ClassFileWalker walker = new ClassFileWalker();
List<File> files = walker.getFiles("C:/files_to_be_compiled");
```