# read multiple xml files from the folder and write one output text file(comma separated)

Tags: java

I need to read all the input xml files from the folder and write one output text file, comma separated. I have the following code program read one file, can someone please help me to modify it and read all the files from the c:/java/ folder. thanks

```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import org.w3c.dom.*;
   import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
   import javax.xml.parsers.*;
   import javax.xml.xpath.*;

    public class XPathExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
                SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

            DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("c:/java/test.xml");

            XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//FORM[@name='F00001']        /*/text()");

            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
            }

            }

             }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to iterate all files in your directory:

[Read all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Output (file in dir) use as input here

```
Document doc = builder.parse("<dir file>");
```

If file is not xml, it either return null or exceprion is raised (I dont know currently). Eitherway, you will have to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the files in the directory `C:\java` you can use the code:

```
for (File file : new File("C:\\java").listFiles()) 
{
   Document doc = builder.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
   ...
}
```

You can play about with where you add the rest of your code around this loop.  You should also add some basic checks that what you're trying to parse is indeed XML too.