# How can I scan whole C drive for playlists

Tags: java, file, directory

At the moment I am using this following code to check my test data folder for m3u (playlist) file:

```
String filename = "test-data\\non-existent-playlist.m3u";
        boolean isHeaderValid = M3UReader.isValidHeader(filename);
        System.out.println(filename + "header tested as "+ isHeaderValid);
```

I would like to be able to make the program scan the whole of the c drive or removable storage for playlists files but I cannot find any similar programs that do this.

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder -- google: java read folder contents

Comment: @fonZ, If folder name is unknown than your link question will not be applicable.

Comment: @Masud there is no difference in searching a folder or the root of a hard drive, those are two exact the same operations, the difference is the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Files.walkFileTree`. This will scan whole drive and search your desired file name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path startingDir = Paths
        .get("C:\\");
    Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, new FindJavaVisitor());
  }

  private static class FindJavaVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {

      if (file.toString().contains("non-existent-playlist.m3u")) {
        System.out.println(file.getFileName());
      }
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
  }
```