# Discovering whether a ZipEntry is a Directory or Not using isDirectory()

Tags: java, unzip, directory-structure

I had planned to use ZipEntry's isDirectory() method to identify whether a zip file contained a directory when validating the file structure of the zip file.

The zip files should have the following file structure:
- content/file1.pdf
- afile.xml
- anotherfile.xml

Every zip file must have a folder which must contain some content. I would like to have been able to rely on isDirectory() to check if there is a directory, for example:

```
//this is part of a unit test which checks the structure of zipped file.
public List<String> unzip(String outpath) { 
    List<String> fnames = new ArrayList<String>();
    try  { 
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(outpath); 
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
        ZipEntry ze = null; 
        boolean contentFound = false; 

        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 

            if(ze.isDirectory()) {  
                contentFound = true; 
            } 
            else { 
                fnames.add(ze.getName());
                zin.closeEntry(); 
            }          
        } 
        zin.close(); 
        assertTrue("Content folder not found", contentFound);
    } catch(Exception e) { 
    } 
    return fnames;
}
```

When isDirectory() was never true despite providing a zip file which contained the content directory, I used the following to see what was being picked up:

```
public List<String> unzip(String outpath) { 
    List<String> fnames = new ArrayList<String>();
    try  { 
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(outpath); 
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
        ZipEntry ze = null; 
        boolean contentFound = false; 

        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
            System.out.println(ze.getName());
            fnames.add(ze.getName());
            zin.closeEntry();     
        } 
        zin.close(); 
        assertTrue("Content folder not found", contentFound);
    } catch(Exception e) { 
    } 
    return fnames;
}
```

Output for this is:

- content/file2.pdf
- content/file1.pdf
- anotherfile.xml
- file.xml

I think isDirectory() is never evaluating to be true because the path "content/file2.pdf" is pointing to a file which is contained in the directory and not to the directory itself. I'm not sure what I have to do to identify the directory on its own using isDirectory(). While I have a work around for this problem I would rather understand why isDirectory() didn't work as I expect that I might be approaching the problem wrong.

The work around for identifying the presence of the folder which is:

```
if (zipEntry.getName().contains("content/")) {
currentJob.contentFolderFound();
...
```

(Note: Credit where credit is due, the original unzip method was derived from this solution:
[Read all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder/23814217#23814217))

Comment: Do you use Java 7? If yes use the ZIP filesystem instead, it's much easier

Comment: Hello fge, unfortunately this project is not using Java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While refactoring the method from where this question came from I have managed to get isDirectory() to evaluate as true when zipEntry is the folder itself (yey!)

I was refactoring while referencing the following guide:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/

It seems that the confusion was from creating ZipEntry within the while (unless you can see any other difference)

```
    ZipInputStream zis;
    ZipEntry zipEntry;
    try {
        zis = new ZipInputStream(filePart.getInputStream());
        zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry(); 
    } catch (IOException ioExc) {
        //do something;
    }
while(zipEntry != null){ //if you run me I will infinitely loop!
    String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
    System.out.println("I am the directory! " +zipEntry.isDirectory() + " " + zipEntry.getName());

}
```

Comment: I see the issue even when the  ZIPEntry is created outside the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit late, but for those who are still looking for a nice way of solving this, here is my answer.

The method ([grepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.java#ZipEntry.isDirectory%28%29)):

```
public boolean isDirectory() {
    return name.endsWith("/");
}
```

where `name` is the same value returned by `ZipEntry.getName()`.

For Windows systems, for example, this should be `"\\"`, hence `ZipEntry.isDirectory` will always return false. To solve this you can use:

```
ze.getName().endsWith(File.separator)
```

instead of

```
ze.isDirectory()
```

Comment: This will only work when the directory is empty, in which case even isDirectory() will work. The moment the directory has a file in it, it doesn't get listed on it's own and instead the files inside it are listed.

Comment: ze.getName().endsWith(File.separator) works for me