# List of files in directory with new File API

Tags: java, file, java-8

In the old API you could get the files in a directory with the methods `File.list()` and `File.listFiles()`. How do you get something similar using the new API? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846349) you can see how to walk through a file tree but what I want is not to go deeper than the first level like `File.list()` does.

To have a little application you could write as answer the code for a program which prints the file names of a directory given by a `java.nio.file.Path` object `path` alphabetically ordered to the standard output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
Files.list(Paths.get("somedir")).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Or in my case: `Files.list(path).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);`