# How to convert a file directory into a List of InputStreams with Java 8

Tags: java, performance, java-8

I want to covert all files inside ROOT directory into java 8 stream of InputStream.

suppose there are a lot of files inside the ROOT

for example file OS:

```
ROOT
 |--> file1
 |--> file2
```

I want to do somethink but using java 8 with the best PERFORMANCE!!

```
List<InputStream> ins = new ArrayList<>();
File[] arr =  new File(ROOT).listFiles()
for(File file: arr){
  ins.add(FileUtils.openInputStream(file));
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? Do you want to read multiple files concurrently? Why do you want to have multiples `InputStream`?

Comment: I want to make copy&paste all files inside my local disk directory into google cloud storage. As i know there is no way to make copy all directory , so i need to do that file by file

Comment: Ah so you want to copy files recursively? Like here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076439/java-8-copy-directory-recursively

Comment: recursive is very slow , i have flat hierarchy...do u have any idea of uploading folder with files into cloud ?

Comment: Did you measure it? And you hierarchy isn't flat, there are multiple sub directories.

Comment: I know i'll edit my question into flat ( without sub-dir)

Comment: Something like this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213409/list-of-files-in-directory-with-new-file-api

Comment: finally the solution :    List<InputStream> ins = Files.list(Paths.get("/Users/vitaly")).sorted().map(l -> {
                try {
                    return Files.newInputStream(l);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @VitalyTarasiuk, it's ok to post answers to your own questions. As a comment, your answer is hidden under "more comments". If you post as an answer we can review your own solution and offer suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: best solution is the one that you have dismissed:

- Use `File.listFiles()` (or equivalent) to iterate over the files in each directory.
- Use recursion for nested directories.

---

Lets start with the performance issue.  When you are uploading a large number of individual files to cloud storage, the performance bottleneck is likely to be the network and the remote server:

- Unless you have an extraordinarily good network link, a single TCP stream won't transfer data anywhere like as fast as it can be read from disk (or written at the other end).
- Each time you transfer a file, there is likely to be an overhead for starting the new file.  The remote server has to create the new file, which entails adding a directory entry, and inode to hold the metadata, etc.
- Even on the sending side, the OS and disc overheads of reading directories and metadata are likely to dominate the Java overheads.

(But don't just trust what I say ... measure it!)

The chances are that the above overheads will be orders of magnitude greater than you can get by tweaking the Java-side file traversal.

---

But ignoring the above, I don't think that using the Java 8 `Stream` paradigm would help anyway.  AFAIK, there are no special high performance "adapters" for applying streams to directory entries, so you would most likely end up with a Stream wrapper for the result of `listFiles()` calls.  And that would not improve performance.

(You might get some benefit from parallel streams, but I don't think you will get enough control over the parallelism.)

Furthermore, you would need to deal with the fact that if your Java 8 `Stream` produces `InputStream` or similar handles, then you need to make sure that those handles are properly closed.  You can't just close them all at the end, or rely on the GC to finalize them.  If you do either of those, you risk running out of file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take it in a consideration !!

Answer (score 0):

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(Root)));

Comment: to your suggestion        :   java.io.IOException: Is a directory
 at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
 at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:159)
 at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
 at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
 at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
 at java.nio.file.Files.read(Files.java:3105)
 at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3158)

Comment: sorry i did not test it at my end but look in that line