# How to check if directory contains file which name contains certain string?

Tags: java, file, dir

I have to find a file ard12333.txt but the number part is variable so I should check if the file contains the string "ard" and then extrapolate the number part. How to do that?

Comment: I don't know how to start.. I know how to check if file exsists in directory but nothing more..

Comment: try with reading file name into string and using string functions

Comment: Java Tutorial [Finding Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps for your work :

1) Fetch the file name from directory.

2) Check whether it contains `ard` or not.

3) If yes, then convert the rest of file name without extension to Integer or Long or whatever Number.
   If No, go to step 1 to check next file if any.

4) If value of variable and converted number matches, wooohhooo you are done.
   Break the loop and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

read all files in folder while checking name. file reading process is in this link.
check this.

[Read files from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folde)

you can check file names start with `String.startsWith()`  method to find start letters in file name string.