# get all video only particular folder

Tags: android, video, media-queries

I want to load all video form particular folder where I want to downloaded. Is it possible to load all video from the particular device folder and play.
I searched but not able to find any solution. I found `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA.` related all video that stored in my device by the media query. But I want to get all video only particular folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you know path of your downloaded video.. than you can use that path to fetch files from that folder.

refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846349/942224)