# Java: More efficient way to read in the directory structure and file info of a whole disk?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, directory

I know how to [recurse](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/recurse.htm) (not re-curse) through a directory structure and get file info etc... e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder) or [that](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68) ;)

**My question is; is there a more efficient way to do this?**

This works well on a 2Gb drive but these days we are using 2Tb and more.  I would like to only get the filesize of each file (even the sum of all files in a directory would help).  Can one read the OS's disk structure file/data somewhere rather than traversing the whole disk? (Btw, what is the apostrophe rule for abbreviations like OS?)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you're currently reading in entire files to compute their length? In that case use [`java.io.File.length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29).

Comment: No, but I have to scan/list each dir and make a file object for each file in that dir to get the file size. (Not reading the content for the file)

Comment: You could read the raw disk, but you would need to understand the underlying file system format.  The problem you have is that a 2 TB disk only spins and its head moves so fast.  If you want more IOPS, you need to use SSD which can be 1000x faster at these sort of operations.

Comment: I can remember vaguely (15 years ago) that the OS kept a file of some sorts that contain the directory structure, some file info and where on the physical disk the file is. I assume it is different for each OS but isn't there some common lib for this?