# How to read the name of the files in a folder using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript hence all mess up with me this time.my doubt is I want to create a JavaScript function which can get the names of all the files in a folder.

Please share your knowledge to get me the basic understanding for this.

Comment: generally - it is impossible

Comment: Javascript in a browser enviroment has no access to the filesystem

Comment: javascript is client side language . The most elegant solution to achieve this is through AJAX.

Comment: JavaScript running where? On a web page? In a browser extension? As a Node.js application? Via Windows Scripting Host? Somewhere else?

Comment: Create / run where (browser, node)? And access files in which "folder"?

Comment: Define "folder". Are you talking about the user's local filesystem?

Comment: It will be deprecated, but [if you want to give a try](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) ...

Comment: If you're new to *programming*, not just JS, you might want to try a language like Python, instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local file access with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because of security, generally you cannot access local files, but in modern browsers you can access some limited files in the sandbox. Your question is completely answered here:
[local-file-access-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: it sounds crazy *Because of security, generally you cannot access local files **how cant you access local files in javascript since java script is client-side language it can access local-files** [read file names in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: Please see my answer- with working code.

Answer (score -2):

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="" webkitdirectory="">
```

JS (modern browsers only):

```
var getFileNames=function(selectorForInput){
    var files=[].reduce.call(document.querySelector(selectorForInput).files,function(files,file){
        files.push(file.name);
        return files;
    },[]);
    return files;
};
getFileNames('#files');
```

Comment: This is everything but an answer to this kind of question

Comment: Sorry! I added more in order to fully answer the question.