# how to get total no of files present in main directory and inside subdirectory, working for everytype of structure in java

Tags: java, file-handling

**suppose my directory structure is as follows:-**
MainFolder
1.file1
2.Folder1
2.1 file2
2.2 file3
2.3 file4
3 file5
4.Folder2
4.1 file6
4.2 file7

**Inside main folder total files are 7 as i know structure so can write code to calculate total no of files in main folder**

```
        public class FileIo {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int count1=0;
        File f=new File("C:\\Users\\omshanti\\Desktop","mainfolder");
         String[] s=f.list();
         for(String s1:s){
             File f1=new File(f,s1);
             if(f1.isFile()){
                 count1++;
             }
             if(f1.isDirectory()){
                      int subdirfilelength=f1.list().length;
                     count1=count1+subdirfilelength;
                 }

             }
         System.out.println("total no of files in h1 folder "+count1);        


     }
 }
```

above code works properly and give total no of files as 7
**but if i dont know file structure, and folder inside main folder also contain subfolder and that folder contain file, so above code not give correct answers,**
for example:-
MainFolder
1.file1
  2.Folder1
2.1 subfolder1
  2.1.1 SubFolderOfSubFolder
     2.1.1.1 file2
    2.1.1.2 file3
    2.1.1.3 file4 
 2.2 file5
  3 file6
  4.Folder2
    4.1 file7
    4.2 file8
***here total no of files is 8,but above code fails***

*finally i got this solution*

```
            int count1=0;
            File f=new File("C:\\Users\\omshanti\\Desktop","h1");
             String[] s=f.list();
             for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                 File f1=new File(f,s[i]);
                 if(f1.isFile()){
                     count1++;

                 }
                 else if(f1.isDirectory()){
                          String[] subdir1=f1.list();
                          for(int j=0;j<subdir1.length;j++){
                              File f2 = new File(f1, subdir1[j]);
                              if (f2.isFile()) {
                                  count1++;


                              }
                              else if(f2.isDirectory()){
                                  String[] subdir2=f2.list();
                          for(int k=0;k<subdir2.length;k++){
                              File f3 = new File(f2, subdir2[k]);

                              if (f3.isFile()) {
                                  count1++;


                              }
                              else if(f3.isDirectory())
                              {
                          String[] subdir3=f3.list();
                                  for (String subdir31 : subdir3) {
                                      File f4 = new File(f3, subdir31);
                                      if (f4.isFile()) {
                                          count1++;


                                      }
                                        }




                         }
                     }

                              }}}

                 }
             System.out.println("total no of files in h1 folder "+count1);
```

Comment: [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html). You may also want to do some research into method recursion (recursive method calls)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505491/list-files-from-directories-and-sub-directories-in-java-including-only-partial-f/12505570#12505570), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580764/listfiles-in-java-fails-to-get-all-files/28581269#28581269)

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons-io's **FileUtils.listFiles** for this:

```
List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File("/your/path"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
int nbFiles = files.size();
```

Their javadoc says:

> Finds files within a given directory (and optionally its
>   subdirectories).

The first parameter is your path. The 2nd sets the flag to 'find files'. The 3rd sets the flag to 'consider directories', thus going through subdirectories.

You need the following dependency in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

or download the jar here and add it to your classpath:
[commons-io:commons-io:2.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4) (or [direct link to download](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar))

FileUtils javadoc on [Apache's site](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Comment: i solved my problem by myself in simple way

Comment: could you post what you did (perhaps add an "edit" section to your question?)

Comment: good. I personally think the 2 liners with commons-io is way more elegant, but hey, if it suits your need. For info, instead of FileUtils.listFiles, if the content is too large, you could also use FileUtils.iterateFilesAndDirs and iterate manually..