# How to read non alphanumeric characters

Tags: java, encoding

How can I read non alphanumeric characters (like Chinese characters) in Java? I tried to read a value from a `.properties` file but I get broken characters in output.

```
filename = some method returning the file in Chinese 

response.setProperty("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName +"\"");
response.setContentType("text/xlscharset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

Comment: Put what you have tried in question.

Comment: Edit question thanks. Code in comments looks unreadable. Include section of settings file too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how are you reading file. I would suggest you to use `BufferedReader` to read file, which is as follows,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream("myFilePath"),"UTF8"));
```

Above piece of code will handle Chinese characters. Now, you car use `br` to process your property file. If your file is `UTF-16`, the replace `UTF8` encoding with `UTF-16` and it should do the job for you.

Comment: In my scenario the File Name itself contains chinese characters. Hence on using the name in the file path, it doesnot recognise the file. If i print the file name at backend, I get broken characters in console.

Comment: You can get filename using the method given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder and then pass the filename to `BufferedReader`.

Comment: My java string contains chinese characters. When I print that it shows broken character. I want my string to contain the chinese characters. Is that possible?

Comment: @JavaLearner Yup, string can contain chinese characters. If you want to show on output screen/console then look at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-eclipse-console/ for settings of eclipse..

Comment: On downloading a file having Chinese Characters in its name, I am getting "File not found exception." But the file is present in the drive and the file name in the "Open and Save" popup is also fine.

Comment: Did you tried getting files using the method shared in my last comment?

Comment: Yes. I gave the file path containing the file name(Chinese).                                                                                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fullPath),"UTF8"));                                                          OutputStream out = response.getPortletOutputStream();    
 byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
int len;                                                          while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0){      ;
     out.write(buf,0,len);
     }

Comment: You can use `br.readLine()` directly to get the content. You needn't use `buf[]`