# How to count images from folders(having sub & sub-sub-folders) using java?

Tags: java, excel

I have 'm' no. of folders with 'n' of sub-folders and 'p' no. of sub-sub-folders inside them, which contain 'i' no. of images in each. Now I want to count and print them in excel sheet (with respective folders name in column).
Note that few 'n' sub-folders may not contain 'p' sub-sub-folders.

Could anyone please explain me briefly with a sample program?

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Comment: It is a big program. Show us what you did till now.

Comment: apache commons provide some [tools](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) for such tasks

Comment: You have two questions, which one do you want answered?

Comment: First please help me with how to count the images.. later i may go for printing them in excel..

Comment: Look at this first: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: First you have to try then post your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Best and simple approach would be using `Apache commons-io` API.

```
    File file = new File("d:\\scan");       
    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(file, null, true);     
    for(File file2 : files){
        System.out.println(file2.getName());            
    } 

    System.out.println( file.length());
```