# List files/subfolders on apache server via HTTP in Java

Tags: java, file, http, io, inputstream

So I can access a file on HTTP using

```
URL url = new URL("www.example.com/file.extension");
```

Then I would get a `InputStream stream = url.openStream();` and do stuff with that. Is there a way that if I specifiy `http://www.example.com/` I can loop through and get a list of all urls to each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not through the http server. If you're running this on the same machine, you can use the normal [Java File API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder).

Comment: Well, not through *most* HTTP servers, *most of the time*. Usually directory indexes are disabled on the root folder.

Answer (score 2):

The server in question was an Apache server. As Nathan said in his comment, directory indexing had to be enabled.

### Enable Indexing

See: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/

#### Approach 1:

1. Open Apache config file: (`etc/httpd/httpd.conf` or `etc/apache2/apache2.conf`)
2. Add the following:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/example.com/directory>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Save and close
4. Restart Apache

#### Approach 2:

1. Create/Open a file called `.htaccess` in directory you want indexed.
2. Append the following line: `Options Indexes`

### Use this in Java

Now that indexing is enabled you can actually access the list of subdirectories/files from your java code.

```
URL url = new URl("http://www.example.com/directory"); //or just "http://www.example.com/" for the root dir, if there isn't an index.html

Scanner sc = new Scann(url.openStream());
while(sc.hasNextLine())
      System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

The output of this snippet will be

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of directory</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Index of directory/</h1>
<ul><li><a href="subdir/">subdir</a></li>
<li><a href="file.txt">file.txt</a></li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

Parse that URL however you choose. You will also get a directory listing as a webpage if you visit `http://www.example.com/directory/`

Comment: Paul, the answer is a summarization of the article

Comment: Yes. You'll notice that the first version of your answer didn't have the summary. I should have deleted my comment when you updated your answer 30 minutes after my comment :)