# jUnit gets NullPointerException when using File functions

Tags: java, file, junit, nullpointerexception

If you need any other information please let me know.

**Short Version:**

This line of code causes a NullPointerException when tested with jUnit 4.12:

```
File[] files = new File(searchPath).listFiles();
```

**Long version:**

First of all, this is the enviroment:

- OS: Win7 Pro (Netbeans runs as Admin)
- IDE: Netbeans 8.0.2
- Build automation tool: Gradle
- Java: JDK 1.8
- Test-Framework: jUnit 4.12

The exception only occurs when i run jUnit-tests.
When i build it without any tests, everything works fine and the function *listFiles()* from *File[] files = new File(searchPath).listFiles()* doesn't return null.

```
gradle clean & gradle build -x test & gradle rest:jettyRun 2> test.txt
```

This is the problem-function, called in the constructor of my class:

```
/**
 * Scans for JSON files on given path
 * @param searchPath full path given
 * @return String[] with the full paths and names of found files
 */
private String[] scanForJsons(String searchPath){
    System.out.println("search path "+searchPath); // shows D:\..\core\files

    File[] files = new File(searchPath).listFiles(); // problem line, allways returns null

    System.out.print(((files!=null)?"Not null" : "Null"));
    System.out.println("files.length: "+files.length);
    String[] stringArray = new String[files.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        String path = files[i].getName();
        if (path.endsWith(".json")) {
            path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 5);
        }
        stringArray[i] = path;
    }
    return stringArray;
}
```

Comment: Now it's not clear whether the problematic line *returns* null or throws an exception. Your text says one thing, the comment says another. Also, please provide the unit test in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the description of **java.io.File**, **java.nio.file** should be used to overcome limitations from **java.io.File**.

After i reworked the whole function and migrated from [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and Strings to [java.nio.file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) and Path it works fine.

The code was found at [Read all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder).

```
private List<Path> scanForJsons(Path pathScanned){
    List<Path> pathList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
            Files.walk(pathScanned).forEach(filePath -> {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                pathList.add(filePath);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pathList;
}
```

Even if i don't need it anymore i wrote the function to get just the filenames without the file extension:

```
//Get a list of the filenames without the filename extension
private List<String> getRawNamesOfFiles(String filenameExtension){
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Files.walk(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().getParent()).forEach(filePath -> {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                String fileName = getRawNameOfFile(filePath, filenameExtension);
                if(fileName != null){
                    fileNames.add(fileName);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileNames;
}

// removes the filename extension 
// checks if the file extension of the path fits the wanted filename extension, returns null if it doesn't fit
private String checkAndEditTheName(Path path, String wantedFilenameExtension){
    int cutLength = wantedFilenameExtension.length() + (wantedFilenameExtension.startsWith(".")?0:1);
    String pathEnd = path.getFileName().toString();
    if(pathEnd != null && pathEnd.endsWith(wantedFilenameExtension)){ //search for a specific filename extension
        pathEnd = pathEnd.substring(0, pathEnd.length() - cutLength); // remove the filename extension and the point
        return pathEnd;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) includes:

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

So it looks like that's what's happening. A path of `d:\..\core\files` doesn't look like a valid pathname to me... how can you expect a directory to be the parent of a root directory?

You need to change your test to provide a valid path - and quite possibly change your method to cope with `listFiles()` potentially returning `null`.

Comment: Actually it's a valid pathname. I just shortened it in my comments with .. because there was my real name in it.

[Edit] That is the full path:   D:\OneDrive\MyName\Projekte\Java\REST\Projekt_Abgabe\Rechteverwalltung\Data\core\files

Comment: @ZeugeDerUnity: Well that's not terribly helpful, is it? I suggest you try logging `File.exists(searchPath)` and `File.isDirectory(searchPath)`... I still expect the problem is due to the path being inappropriate in some way.

Comment: I addet the following line on top of the mentioned function:
`File directory = new File(searchPath);
System.out.println("Is directory?: " + (directory.isDirectory()?"Yes":"No"));`


When i run the jUnit-Test: **Is directory?: No**
When i build it without the tests and run it with jettyRun: **Is directory?: Yes**

Comment: Well what is the path? If it's a relative path, it may well be a matter of where the tests run from... Try printing out `directory.getCanonicalPath()`.

Comment: Ok, it says:  D:\OneDrive\MyName\Projekte\Java\REST\Projekt_Abgabe\Rechteverwalltung\Data\core‌​\files (with jUnit and jettyRun)

Comment: @ZeugeDerUnity: So have you tried running the tests from the command line JUnit test runner, without getting Gradle and jettyRun involved? You basically need to narrow it down - although unit tests hitting the file system is *usually* a bad idea anyway.

Comment: No i didn't know that i could run test from console, i'll look that up and try immediately. Actually it's my first time using this framework. I did some experiments by myself and figured out, that there is no problem for the jUnit-tests to use `File[] files = new File(searchPath).listFiles();` . The problem occurs, when the test tries to use the class with *scanForJsons* in the constructor. I'll try to get a StackTrace.