# Loop to access specific files?

Tags: java, java-io

I have 700 files in one folder, each one with a number 1-700, with the file extension .pkmn. I created them and changed their data with a program, but now how would I access them? I've tried a for loop with the path + i + ".pkmn", but it didn't work. How would I access them and assign them to a File?

Thank you.

Comment: can you elaborate with your effort?

Comment: Didn't work? Do you get an error? Can you show us the code as well as location of files, pattern of file name.

Comment: Please show your code and the error message, exceptions. "but it didn't work" is not very helpfull.

Comment: You can try with: `File[] files = new File("directory").listFiles()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read all files in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'll add it when I get home. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listFiles()` method, that returns an array of files in a directory:

```
File directory = new File("directory path");
File[] createdFiles = directory.listFiles();
for (File createdFile : createdFiles) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the methods of java nio file instead of the "old" io package! It is much faster.

```
Path dir = ...;
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir)) {
    for (Path file: stream) {
        System.out.println(file.getFileName());
    }
} catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException x) {
    // IOException can never be thrown by the iteration.
    // In this snippet, it can only be thrown by newDirectoryStream.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#listdir