# Java 7 - File.listFiles() cost of this operation

Tags: java, java-7

I have a scenario where I have to loop through file contents for multiple purposes. My question here is, is it Ok to call `file.listFiles()` multiple times? Is this an expensive operation? Or should I store this this into a variable and use it in all the places?

The problem here is. I may have 3 or 4 levels. In each level, I have to validate or carry some logics. I have to start from the folder 1 and do logic 1 till folder 4. Then again I have to start from folder 1 to perform logic 2 and then for logic 3 and so on.

```
Folder 1
 - Folder 2
 - File1
      - Folder 3
      - File2
           - Folder 4
           - File3
```

Comment: It might not be too costly in performance, but what are the consequences if a file is added / removed midway through your operation and logic 2 is performed on one or more files without it having been processed by logic 1?  Keeping the file listing in memory would prevent this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

As per my Java experience I dont think operation is costly, It take n time to get all the file, where n is number of file.You can write recursive program to read the all directory of the folder.Recursive code will be easy to write but may little bit slower in performance.

```
 There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will  
 appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to   
  appear in alphabetical order.  

  Note that the Files class defines the newDirectoryStream method to open a 
  directory and iterate over the names of the files in the directory. This 
  may use less resources when working with very large directories.
```

[See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--)

[See here Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

**Bottom Line Up Front (BLUF):** Calling `file.listFiles()` multiple times will likely cause little/no impact on performance.

I wrote a test case to measure the amount of time it takes to list the contents of a local directory 10,000 times. I used a 2.9Ghz dual-core Windows 10 machine. There were 45 files of varying size in the directory. Here's the test case:

```
class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = Paths.get(System.getProperties().get("user.home")+"").toFile();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            f.listFiles()[0].toString();
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total Time = " + (endTime - startTime));
    }
}
```

It produced the following output on the first run:

```
Total Time = 1337
```

This means that it takes less than 1ms to list the files.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
    Path searchPath = Paths.get("c://log");
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> fileList = Files.newDirectoryStream(searchPath)) {
      for (Path path : fileList) {
        System.out.println(path.getFileName());
      }
```

Its less resource intensive and provides overloaded methods for pattern matching too.