# regex for getting the fileName

Tags: java, regex, xml

I am having a file name like suppose `abcde-1_Transformed.xml`.

Now if I have many number of files suppose in the above file name the `'1'` which is present has files like
`abcde-2_Transformed.xml`.
`abcde-3_Transformed.xml`.
`abcde-4_Transformed.xml`.
till `abcde-1966_Transformed.xml`.

How to get the file names which are not present in the total number of files using regex ?

Comment: your question is not clear. do you mean you need a file that does not fall between abcde-1_Transformed.xml and abcde-1966_Transformed.xml?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own.
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: "How to get the file names which are not present"?  Isn't your output going to be infinite?

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than making a regex you can just read the file in the current directory using this link [Read all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Then parse out the number from file name and check if it's present or not.