# Why keep receiving java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied) error?

Tags: java, string, file

I am trying to load image file from file directory. Then, I want to convert the file object to string object. Unfortunately, I keep receive this error messages. How can I resolve it?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\workspace\sesaja\Images (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at test.Test1.main(Test1.java:29)
```

> Thi is my overall code

```
 public class Test1 {

     public static void main(String args[]){        

    String s = System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator")+ "Images";
    File f = new File (s);

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    String str = "";

     try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                // convert to char and display it
                str += (char) content;
            }

            System.out.println("After reading file");
            System.out.println(str);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }      
    }           

}
```

Comment: Is E:\workspace\sesaja\Images a file or a directory?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO it is a file directory

Comment: Are you trying to read from a Directory? It's a dir not a file

Comment: @AlirezaMohamadi Actually I have a set of images folder in the working directory. I am trying to load the image file from that folder. Is it wrong with my code. How can i change it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read all files in a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate desired file name at the end of this line:

```
String s = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
System.getProperty("file.separator")+ "Images" + fileName;
```

It seems you are trying to read data from a directory, which is not logically correct.
Also using `FileInputStream` in order to read characters (not data) is not recommended. You may use a `BufferedReader` instead.
Also for getting name of files inside a directory, you may read this: [Read all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: The filename means my file image name? "Images" is the name of folder images and I  am trying to read all the images from that folder, not only to read one image.

Can you show me how to use Bufferedreader?