# File Lambda expression in Java 7

Tags: java, lambda, java-7

The below code works fine in Java 8.

```
files.addAll(Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles((f) -> f.getName()
                .endsWith(CustomConstantsRepository.FILE_EXT_DAT)
                && f.getName().startsWith(fileName))));
```

I need the same functionality to work in Java 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See, essentially [Read all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846349) and then add validation in the else for the name for the suffix and beginning.

Comment: Try this [third party](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) it is awesome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use an [Anonymous Inner Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), as Java 8 lambda expressions are essentially syntatical sugar which do nearly the same thing. That would look something like this.

```
files.addAll(Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles(new FileFilter(){

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.getName().endsWith(CustomConstantsRepository.FILE_EXT_DAT) && f.getName().startsWith(fileName)));
        }

})));
```