# search through files that have unix timestamp extension using java

Tags: java, file, unix, search, timestamp

I have files such:

```
buy.txt.xxx
buy.txt.yyy
buy.txt.zzz ...
```

Where xxx, yyy and zzz are unix timestamp
I want to allow user to search in limited date:
For example the user will enter these three variables(`startDate,endDate,wordToSearch`):

```
Text Field1: 2017-05-01
Text Field2: 2017-05-05
Text Field3: wordToSearch
```

And the **java** app will convert **startDate** and **endDate** entered by user to 
Unix timestamp and **loop through the files** to get **the lines contain the wordToSearch.**
How I can implemented such this in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can create file name like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date searchDate = dateFormat.parse("2017-05-01");
    long timestamp = searchDate.getTime();
    String filename = "buy.txt."+timestamp;
```

After  that search through filename like you did before.

Comment: In that case you can read all the filenames within a folder using https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846349/1967285 and from file name get the timestamp part using split method. Then check if that timestamp is within given range or not. If yes then open the file and start searching else move to another file

Comment: I will try that.