# Find and list all files/folders in a folder in Haxe

Tags: haxe

This question is in principal the same like these ones here

- [How to read all files in a folder from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-folder-from-java)
- [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory#3207973)
- ...

But is there a way to do the same in on sys target platforms in Haxe, without running `ls` / `dir` via `sys.io.Process` and parsing the results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`sys.FileSystem.readDirectory(path)`](https://api.haxe.org/sys/FileSystem.html?#readDirectory) for this.

> Returns the names of all files and directories in the directory specified by `path`.
>
> If `path` does not denote a valid directory, an exception is thrown.
>
> If `path` is null, the result is unspecified.

If you need files to be listed *recursively*, [this article](https://code.haxe.org/category/beginner/using-filesystem.html) from the Haxe Code Cookbook is a good reference (there's a section titled "Recursive loop through all directories / files").