# how to take the files from the path given in jtextfield in java GUI

Tags: java

I have to create an exe file using java GUI in eclipse. In this tool I have a jButton and a jTextField. In the jTextField I will give the source path where new/updated file is there. I want that when I click the jbutton the files in the path should fetched for further processing. Please help me in doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-folder-from-java

Comment: Have you read the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)? You need to pay attention to the section "Get answers to practical, detailed questions".  You need to show the code of what you have accomplished so far, and then only ask a **single** question about a **single** issue that keeps you from moving forward.  Stack Overflow does not exist to get people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Add an event listener to the JButton

```
showDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void action(ActionEvent e)
  {
     ProcessFile(textField.getText());
  }

});
```

You process file function could look something like this

```
void ProcessFile(string fileName) {

    File folder = new File(fileName);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
      if (file.isFile()) {
          System.out.println(file.getName());
      }
    }
}
```

Please provide some examples of what you have tried before posting.

Comment: Sure Wamadahama, from next time I will provide my code also. Thanks that you tried helping me.

Comment: How many arguments does `ProcessFile` take?  How many did you pass in your listener?