# How can I add images in the postgres table from image folder

Tags: postgresql

I have a customer table in postgres and I want to insert the images for the customer data. I have images of the customers in a folder. I have named all the images name with their customerid.

Now I want to update customer table with their respective image in photo column which is of byte data type. Even though it's bad idea to store images in a database, my image size is small and I need to do that.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could indicate what platform you are running on, what languages you have available.  PHP, Python, Ruby, and many other languages could do this with ease.

Comment: I am using JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

I would start here for an understanding of processing the files in Java.
[How to read all files in a folder from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-folder-from-java)

Then take a look at the docs on this topic at postgresql.org:
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html

**For a database table like this:**

```
CREATE TABLE images (imgname text, img bytea);
```

**To insert an image, you would use:**

```
File file = new File("myimage.gif");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, file.getName());
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int)file.length());
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
fis.close();
```