# I have 900 file in a folder which are in .pdf formatt.i have to convert .pdf to .csv one by one and store those csv in another folder

Tags: java, itext

here I am doing for one file and store in another folder. how to do it for multiple files?

```
try 
{ 
     Document document = new Document();
     document.open();
     FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pdf\\MyCSVFile.csv");
     StringBuilder parsedText=new StringBuilder();
     PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pdf\\NL-26.pdf");
     int n = reader1.getNumberOfPages();
     for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) 
     {
        parsedText.append(parsedText+PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader1, i+1).trim()+"\n") ;
     }
     StringReader stReader = new StringReader(parsedText.toString());
     int t;
     while((t=stReader.read())>0)
         fos.write(t);
         document.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the files under the given directory using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1844695/2504962):

```java
final File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pdf");
final File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    final File file = listOfFiles[i];
    if (file.isFile() && file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".pdf")) {
        parsePdf("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pdf\\MyCSVFile"+i+".csv", file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

If you refactor your business logic to a separate method then you can use it from the `if`.

```java
private static void parsePdf(final String fileToWrite, final String fileToRead) throws IOException {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite)) {
        final StringBuilder parsedText = new StringBuilder();
        final PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(fileToRead);
        int n = reader1.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            parsedText.append(parsedText + PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader1, i + 1).trim() + "\n");
        }
        final StringReader stReader = new StringReader(parsedText.toString());
        int t;
        while ((t = stReader.read()) > 0)
            fos.write(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this assuming every file inside of the directory ends in pdf?  What if there is another file type in that directory?

Comment: It's just an assumption. It would be logical to put only .pdf's to a folder named `pdf` if someone want to parse a lot of .pdf. :) Of course we can check the extension of the file as another condition in the if case.

Comment: You say that but you are literally outputting all the `.csv` files into the folder called `pdf`.  So you are already breaking your own logic.  You shouldn't just _assume_ that the code will be used correctly and not account for it.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. Updated my answer according to them. :)

Comment: @Roshni why it showing error it showing change pdfReader to string

Comment: Updated my answer. You have to modify the `parsePdf("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pdf\\MyCSVFile"+i+".csv", file.getAbsolutePath());` and the `private static void parsePdf(final String fileToWrite, final String fileToRead) throws IOException {` lines.

Comment: Use the above mentioned two new lines in your program. I changed the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this:

```
public static void convertAllCSV(String directory)
{
    try 
    {
        ArrayList<String> files = findFiles(directory); //Returns list of all files in folder with .pdf extension

        for (String s : files)
        {
            convertSingleCSV(s, directory); //Your current code placed into a method
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

With the `findFiles` method looking like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> findFiles(String directory) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File dir = new File(directory);

    String ext = ".pdf";
    String[] files = dir.list();
    for (String file : files)
    {
        //If the file ends with .pdf
        if(file.endsWith(ext))
        {
            fileList.add(file);
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

There are basically 2 steps you need to add.  You need to pass a directory name and find all the files in the directory with the extension `.pdf` and then use it to call your original method one at a time through a loop.

`convertSingleCSV` is your code placed into a method then uses the filename and directory to output the new file.  So instead of hard coding name of the `FileOutputStream` just convert it by doing something like this:

```
String fileNameNoExtension = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));  //Cuts off the file extension to append csv instead of pdf
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directory + "\\" + fileNameNoExtension + ".csv")
```

The advantage of doing it this way is you keep the original file names but just create a new file with the `.csv` extension, and it will only attempt to convert any `.pdf` files and you do not have to worry about ensuring other files are not in the directory passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `java.nio` library since Java 7:

```java
try(DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Path.of("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pdf\\"), "*.pdf")) {
    stream.forEach(path -> {
        // process the current PDF file (path.toFile to access java.io.File)
    });
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // fail !
}
```