# how to store all filename in Dataset?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've a directory(/home/linus/data/) and having multiple files of different extensions.

Want to collect all file names only which are having extension `.pat` and store in Dataset.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: just read it with regex, example: spark.read.text("*.pat") it should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read all files in a folder from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-folder-from-java)

Comment: @ShemTov, dont want to read content of file, but just file names only. Will it work ?