# How to use DirectoryStream in java 6?

Tags: java-6, java.nio.file

I have below code which is working correctly in Java 7. But how can I make it work for Java 6??

```
        List<Map<String, String>> map = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(Path))) { //auto close stream
            for (Path path : stream) {
                Map<String, String> fileList = new HashMap<>();
                BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                if (!Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                    byte[] filepath = path.toFile().toURI().toURL().toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                    String encodedPath = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(filepath);
                    long time = attr.lastModifiedTime().toMillis();
                    fileList.put("filename", path.getFileName().toString());
                    fileList.put("date", String.valueOf(time));
                    fileList.put("path", encodedPath);
                    map.add(fileList);
                }
            }

            sortArray(map);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Folder not found " + Path);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }
```

I know `try-catch` need to be changed to work in java 6. So can just use like below. However, how do I declare the directory stream? since java 6 not support the diamond operator `<>`

```
        try{
            
        } catch (){
            
        }
```

Comment: DirectoryStream wasn't introduced until Java 1.7 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html

Comment: Noted. So in this case what is the best or easiest alternative for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-folder-from-java This might help