# Serenity BDD: How can I download a file using Serenity + selenium combination?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, serenity-bdd

I am new to Serenity BDD. Usually what I do is to set the firefox preferences.

```
        FirefoxProfile   profile = new FirefoxProfile();

            //Set Location to store files after downloading.
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:\\WebDriverDownloads");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

        //Set Preference to not show file download confirmation dialogue using MIME types Of different file extension types.
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;"); 

        profile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
        profile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
```

But in Serenity where  and how can I use these profiles?
Is there any way for me to set the preferences in serenity.properties file?

Comment: Take a look at the Serenity documentation for firefox profiles:  http://www.thucydides.info/docs/serenity/#_serenity_webdriver_support_in_junit.  There is a section for configuring the webdriver.firefox.profile and firefox.preferences.

Comment: I have read those. I am actually new to automation and coding. So what I did was using serenity jbehave archtype, added a project. It had stories under src/test/resources folder. Added stories there and later mapped those stories to the java code using jbehave. I am still confused where to add those code for firefox profile.

Comment: Finally done by adding preferences in pom.xml file

Comment: Just had to do this the other day. This question was the first hit in Google, but no answer. Find my solution below. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Serenity BDD does not have a specific way to download a file. You will have to use driver options, similar to what you have usually been doing.

There is *[A short guide on how to configure ChromeDriver in Serenity BDD](https://johnfergusonsmart.com/configuring-chromedriver-easily-with-serenity-bdd/)*. [Firefox](https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/serenity-system-properties.html#_firefox_preferences) and other browsers have a similar approach.

Setting these options in `serenity.properties` might not be ideal. First, everything in this file must be static - you cannot have different values based on OS or environment. Second, download paths (for example in Chrome the `chrome_preferences.download.default_directory` option) must be global - you might not know what this value will be at run-time. A potential solution is to set these in your pom; something like:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>features.*.*Story</include>
    </includes>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <chrome_preferences.download.prompt_for_download>false</chrome_preferences.download.prompt_for_download>
      <chrome_preferences.download.default_directory>${project.build.directory}/downloads</chrome_preferences.download.default_directory>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
        <goal>verify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The above will always use a known location to download files, regardless if you are running on Window or Linux, or on your local machine or on Jenkins. To further parameterize this, you could use [Maven Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

The next problem will be to find the file you just downloaded, so that you can do something with it. I tried the [solutions discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34548041/3124333), but I was not able to get those to work in [headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57004031/3124333).

Eventually I came up with this **Chrome-only** solution, which should work whether you are running through Maven or just debugging in your IDE. Firefox and other browsers will use different locations - the `downloads` location below.

```
public class DownloadedFile implements Question<File> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadedFile.class);

    private DownloadedFile() { }

    @Override
    public File answeredBy(Actor actor) {

        File downloads;
        if (System.getProperty("chrome_preferences.download.default_directory") != null)
            downloads = new File(System.getProperty("chrome_preferences.download.default_directory"));
        else if (System.getProperty("headless.mode") != null && System.getProperty("headless.mode").contentEquals("true"))
            downloads = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        else
            downloads = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads");
        log.debug("searching: " + downloads.getPath());
        
        // credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/286001/3124333
        File[] files = downloads.listFiles(File::isFile);
        File chosenFile = null;
        long lastModifiedTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.lastModified() > lastModifiedTime) {
                    chosenFile = file;
                    lastModifiedTime = file.lastModified();
                }
            }
        }
        log.debug("found: " + chosenFile.getAbsoluteFile());

        return chosenFile;
    }

    public static Question<File> filename() {

        return new DownloadedFile();
    }
}
```