# Why local chrome-urls like: chrome://downloads or chrome://apps doesn't work in headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am trying to visit chrome local urls. But it's not working. Does headless chrome support local urls?

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for exactly this just today.

Found this:

> Most chrome internal pages are not implemented in headless mode. This is a limitation of headless Chrome itself, and is not related to ChromeDriver. If you need a particular internal page available in headless Chrome, please file a feature request at https://crbug.com/.

:(

[source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/chromedriver-users/UbgIiMycjWs/fvk8jadcBQAJ)