# Selenium Chrome headless mode "Downloads" ('chrome://downloads/') page is empty

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to find the failed downloads and retrying using below code in chrome using selenium. It is perfectly working in normal mode but when i start the chrome in headless mode. the downloads page is coming as empty due to with it fails.

```
resume_list = browser.driver.execute_script('''

    var tag = document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot;
    var item_tags = tag.querySelectorAll('downloads-item');
    var item_tags_length = item_tags.length;
    var rsm_lst = [];
    for(var i=0; i<item_tags_length; i++) {
        var intag = item_tags[i].shadowRoot;
        var resume_tag = intag.getElementById('pauseOrResume');
        if(resume_tag) {
            var resume = resume_tag;
            resume_tag.click()
            rsm_lst.push(resume);
        }
    }
    return rsm_lst

    ''')
```

Can some one please help me how to do this is headless mode

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/q/57004031/3124333